# Azure Repo support in Azure API Management, or custom repos

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is it possible to configure Azure Repos or custom repos? This provides more functionalities including branching policy, pull request and code review.

Currently, Git is enabled by default, pointing to Azure centralised database.
[image]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-configuration-repository-git

Answer (score 0):

In short:
No, this is not possible.

The longer answer:
No, I don't think this is possible.

Although there's no documentation that states it *is not* possible, I can also not find any documentation it *is* possible. And the lack of UI, REST APIs or documentation on how to specify a custom Git repo leads me to believe this is currently not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The SCM endpoint is one of the managed service components hence it is out of your control.